# STM32L4 hung on debug on HAL_GetTick() but work on step by step debug

Tags: stm32, freeze

I am using `STM32L4` for my project in Eclipse IDE for Embedded C/C++ Developers. The code hung on debug on `HAL_GetTick()` but work on step by step debug. I am using implementation of HAL mbed.
When I pause debug I get the following error
`Can't find a source file at "/builds/ws/mbed-os-ci_mbed2-build-GCC_ARM@2/mbed-os/targets/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32L4/TARGET_STM32L476xG/device/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_stm32l476xx.S"`
Further more in the same project outside of the class that I call the HAL_GetTick the function works fine.

Comment: I think you should add a language tag and also show your code.

Comment: You do not show any code and do not provide any details about crash. If you use STMCubeIDE, go to **Window** menu > **Show View** > **Fault Analyzer** and attach screenshot. Current question is unanswerable. From description you post it seems that code actualy crash somewhere else. There is almost no way the default HAL_GetTick can crash. See it's sources: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32l4xx_hal_driver/blob/eb4b2d2abad64c85000fb883a9fb86ab9fa07a91/Src/stm32l4xx_hal.c#L338-L341